# Encapsulating arguments of variadic function in a class instance

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, function-pointers, variadic-functions

Here some code with holes:

```
template<typename... Args>
class A 
{

  typedef function_type = void(*)(Args...);

  public:
  void set_args(Args&& ... args)
  {
      // something magic manages to encapsulate
      // args in instance of A
  }
  void apply_args(function_type function)
  {
      // something magic manages to "retrieve"
      // the encapsulated args
      function(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }

};
```

Would that be somehow possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store your template arguments in class data member of [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) type and the use [`std::apply`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) in order to apply stored arguments to provided function.

So, let's say you have an `Action` class like this:

```cpp
template <typename... Args>
class Action {
    std::tuple<Args...> args_;

public:
    Action() = default;
    Action(Args&&... args)
        : args_(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    {}

    void args(Args&&... args) {
        args_ = std::make_tuple<Args...>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    template <typename F>
    void apply(F&& fun) {
        std::apply(std::forward<F&&>(fun), args_);
    }
};
```

where you set arguments through constructor `Action action(1, 2, 3);` or through separate function `action.set(3, 2, 1);`.

Then your main function can look like this:

```cpp
int main() {
    Action action(1, 2);

    action.apply([](int a, int b) {
        std::cout << "a + b = " << (a + b) << std::endl;
    });

    return 0;
}
```

Check [live example](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEJNJb0AGTy1MAOWMAjTMRABmd6QAOqBYXVaPUMTQV9/NTobO0cjFzdJAFZFZUxVQIYCZmICYONTcyUVSNpM7IJoh2dXDy8FLJy80M5FBorbKriapIBKRVQDYmQOAHIpd1tkQywAanF3HQIDb3Z57HEABgBBccnpzDmF9XriTGYjNc2dyQnaKYNZ%2BZ0qAzuStkvtq4JMIxXmH6HRYAT28WnOmAAdNCZltiMAFJ8tlNmAoFLD0nQ5gB2WTbGYEmb1dAgEBLFaYJ5whHQyFrGbZBEAfXmeJ2228BicrDwyBAV0JGJKEB6hwAIjMsFRmAZWARWQLCcjhdTEZIAGxSdW0hnwhQ9RWCgkgXXMiDE0k0YgAd2y6CperWEEZ%2BtpBvxhPEuK9YquhpmADdUHh0KaFBBVVqtTqXaKvWyjYSXUzxUSCCSQEZmABrTBM8mrBaq2lOi0gK224j2ouO9zYZ16npuhUegk%2Bv2tmY/P7CQFPAig8FGA4AMSRgqDIYZ3hWwIgY41WpmL1oce9ncFZeYM9Yc7LFbtTwXmsXdeorz6YaZBvcCc92N9XwfLfZW1sBBmWdsIpxd4JysCBlMVoCAWhmSQbzZf1mGAyFt1nCBxESWREjFCB3wZUgZgwpw1z/I0yzQAwPyeJ45kkSRmHI6QZicVMpEkIEyOdajaLjBYyLLSxWBfQUfUgjstkFU4lmIWgZg2F8fRGPpWBAEZEhGUhTBGDYlNQeSdDkOQiQGIYDnGTglIIeS1J6PpsxAbgAE5IQADkSGzuHVTwNh4SROHVIR5O4JSVLU0gNJGJSFBADZSBM1SZNIOBYBgRAUFQP48HYMgKAgNBktSkAEVobcFAQVACFIKgUp%2BYhQogJxTKUpxbGyYF5KM0hMuHegAHlaF3GrSCwLNRHYHr8FOdIA0wUKoosAAPNJiNGAL32UHqeScYgGr0LAmuM4g8CMLa%2BhoegmDYDgeH4MwhBEMRtJkIQ8CcULID6VBvBKCaAFpiXmMUJBkOROGxELUmAzRtCaUwWksSpYniMI/ACOhwbhiJAmh6o3BaIo0hKMpGn0fJBCx4DcfaGJ0cJtokcxto0a6DG%2BgUPThi4WT5MU5SeqCqa7PVd71W4GZgGQZAZggAhiFebNRQgXBCBIcj3DAvQstcBWIJmLS/pkYyavM0hLMSDZIR4Q3EncdV1WshzsTs7hkjkkZfNIPbDY5yagpCsKIt1mL4ogJABgITlivSzLvBS7oLHwIgMZKuhGBYQazutNbvH27yFL8zn5PGRjrUIBAZm53n%2BcF4XRfFyWeh1qK9YQM4sDcEUM6dl3wv89T5M98LIrMiyQEN427Y2M2LatxIbbtjP3Cz92u%2B92vWZGSRZ4Cj2F770gxoqwIrKAA%3D)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [std::tuple](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) and [std::apply](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>
#include <string>

template <typename... Ts>
class A
{
    private:
        std::function<void (Ts...)> f;
        std::tuple<Ts...> args;    
    public:
        template <typename F>
        A(F&& func, Ts&&... args)
            : f(std::forward<F>(func)),
              args(std::make_tuple(std::forward<Ts>(args)...))
        {}

        void Invoke()
        {
            std::apply(f, args);
        }
};

template <typename F, typename... Args>
A<Args...> Create(F&& f, Args&&... args)
{
    return A<Args...>(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main()
{
    auto helloWorld = Create([] (std::string a, std::string b) { std::cout << a << ", " << b; }, std::string("Hello"), std::string("World!"));

    helloWorld.Invoke();
}
```